# Monic generator of an ideal

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm looking for the monic generator of an ideal.  In particular, I've already shown that 
$$M=\{f\in \mathbb{Q}[x]|f(0)=0\}$$
is an ideal because if we take an element from $M$, and multiply it by an element of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, the result is $0$ and $0\in M$.  But as far as a monic generator, I'm a little confused.  Is a monic generator an element of $M$ that generates all elements of $M$?  Since it's kind of analogous to a multiplier, does the structure it is multiplied by need to be an element of $M$ as well or is it an element of the base structure?

In the case of my example above, I would think a generator would be any polynomial with rational coefficients 
$$q=c_1x+c_2x^2+...+c_nx^n$$
since $q(0)=0$.  Then $qf=0$ for all $f\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$.  Is this the correct thinking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generator you are looking for is $x$. Its multiples are precisely elements of the form
$$c_1x+c_2x^2+...+c_nx^n$$
which belong to the ideal. Indeed, every element $q\in M$ in the ideal is of the form $q=x\cdot f$ where $f\in\mathbb Q[x]$.

When this happens, we say that $M$ is the **principal ideal generated by $x$** and we write
$$M=\langle x\rangle\qquad \text{or}\qquad M=(x)$$

Comment: Okay, that was easy.  Is it also true though that any polynomial with no constant term is a generator though?  I can see that $x$ is the best candidate, but can't $(x+1)$ also generate $M$?

Comment: As you say, any other polynomial such as $2x$ or $x/3$ is a valid generator too. For $x+1$ we have a problem, $x+1\not\in M$!

Comment: Ah yes.  I get it.  Thanks!

Comment: So it is the only monic generator.  If i claimed $x^2+x$ was a generator, it could be shown that since $x\in M$, $(x^2+x)g\neq x$ where $g\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, right?

Comment: Generators are unique up to units (in this case, that means multiplication by a rational number). The method you propose to show $x^2+x$ is not a generator works perfectly.